# Maven setting.xml equivalent for sbt

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

To keep artifacts separate, origin of packages differentiated and my development environments clean; I use separate `settings.xml` files for groups of projects. So  and I invoke maven with command as:

```
mvn -s $PROJECT_ROOT/mvn_settings.xml compile
```

How can I configure sbt in a similar way? My workplace provides an internally hosted JFrog repository which has sbt and Ivy plugins enabled. I have tried looking up search engine with various keyword but couldn't find matching documentation.
I use IntelliJ Idea CE with Scala plugin, if this is relevant.

**Edit 1:**  I want to be able to control where my artifacts are stored, their origin and their association with individual projects.

**Edit 2:** Consider two settings.xml's

1. For my random project with minimal libs from maven central: https://pastebin.com/nLc1PGa3
2. My company's projects in one big bin: https://pastebin.com/R6a4jGQC All from separate sources, in their own respective folders. Also I can move my projects independently, not worrying which dependency link might break something else unrelated.

Comment: *I want to be able to control where my artifacts are stored, their origin and their association with individual projects.* does repository management not solve associating the artifacts? Or is it something like you want to have a different repository for each project?

Comment: A different repository for each project, and let those local copies of artifacts be in different directories. This I can achieve in Maven. How to do so in sbt it mystery to me.

Comment: I still didn't get your concern. Could you explain the structure that you are able to obtain using maven already in the question please.

Comment: Consider two settings.xml's

1. For my random project with minimal libs from maven central: http://pastebin.com/nLc1PGa3

2. My company's projects in one big bin: http://pastebin.com/R6a4jGQC

All from separate sources, in their own respective folders. Also I can move my projects independently, not worrying which dependency link might break something else unrelated.

Comment: Looking at the `settings.xml` I doubt the way you are inferring things about maven. In the **first** link shared by you(minimal libs) you are actually specifying a directory on your local machine instead of `.m2` to save the artifacts built by maven in. While in the **second** link shared(company's project) you've specified various paths of repositories from where you would want maven to fetch the artifacts if not already found in your local maven repository.

Comment: Also would suggest adding the details mentioned in the comment by you to the question to add to its value.

Comment: Usually companies keep mirrors of libraries in their repo, so mostly its always there.
This is exactly what I want to do, both local repo's are now different from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though anytime later or soon I would suggest the same practice as by @khmarbaise to be followed in any of the projects that you are building.
Since there seems to be no point of keeping different folders for repositories if they are from the same `group` and `artifact` or even if they are different with `maven`/`sbt` providing the support to *build different projects using differently specified dependencies*.

Similar to maven there can be a [Build Settings Concatenation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html#reminder-it-s-all-immutable) for `build.sbt` which would work  as -

> They are appended in this order:
>
> - Settings from Build.settings and Project.settings in your .scala files.
> - Your user-global settings; for example in ~/.sbt/build.sbt you can define settings affecting all your projects.
> - Settings injected by plugins, see using plugins coming up next.
> - Settings from .sbt files in the project.
> - Build definition projects (i.e. projects inside project) have settings from global plugins (~/.sbt/plugins) added. Using plugins
>     explains this more. Later settings override earlier ones. The entire
>     list of settings forms the build definition.

So you can override your global build.sbt to specify the repository path using

```
"Local Maven" at Path.userHome.asFile.toURI.toURL + ".m2/repository"
```

Comment: Thanks for patiently understanding the problem and providing a solution. The answer by @khmarbaise might be good for use cases but not mine. Over time your local maven repo's grow big, 10GB and a lot of files there are stale. I would purge them. But now I need to refresh all projects and re download the files. This is also one the reasons among many I want to keep separate artifacts per project group.

Answer (score 6):

First grouping things by settings.xml in Maven is not the best way to go. Better is to use the repository manager which can have routes to the particular repositories and to separate repositories and their specific intention. (I'm using a single settings.xml for years which has not been changed. Only the configuration in my repository manager is handling that; This makes life easier and also on CI systems).

Based on the [docs of sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html) you can configure the proxy repositories like this in the `~/.sbt/repositories` file:

```
[repositories]
  local
  my-ivy-proxy-releases: http://repo.company.com/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  my-maven-proxy-releases: http://repo.company.com/maven-releases/
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a Configuration object to do this.

For example in an .sbt file:

```
val MyConfig = Configurations.config("my-config").extend(Compile)

(resolvers in MyConfig) := Seq(???)
```

Then when you use the sbt shell you can call

```
my-config/compile
```

And it will use the settings you've declared only for that scope. 
Then you can declare as many configurations as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for publishing artifacts to your company's internal JFrog repository.

The relevant JFrog documentation can be found here - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/SBT+Repositories#SBTRepositories-DeployingArtifacts

Comment: No. I just want separate artifact directories. e.g. I have different .m2 and .gradle directories for different projects. I user internal repositories for company's work and Maven central for my own code.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at sbt command line help and I found I can set path to local ivy repository using `-ivy` option.